Unable to Compile Any Template Code with cl.exe
I'm attempting to compile some C++ code into a DLL file using cl.exe on Windows 10. It appears that I am unable to compile any code using templates at all because of error C2187, using the Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt.

As a simple example, attempting to compile the following test.cpp file with just one function TestFx that directly returns the templated argument it recieves:
template <typename T>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) T __stdcall TestFx(T arg) {return arg;}

With the command cl.exe /std:c++20 test.cpp, results in:
C2187: syntax error: 'string' was unexpected here


I'm not quite sure what this error is trying to tell me. There appear to be no Visual Studio documentations on error C2187, and it does not appear to have a page on the official Microsoft compiler error list.
At first I thought that this error may be caused by string being undefined when the compiler creates all the template versions of TestFx, but adding include <iostream> or include <string> and using namespace std; yields the same error.
It's even more confusing to me, because attempting to compile something like:
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T TestFx(T arg) 
{ 
    return arg; 
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << TestFx(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << TestFx(5.5) << "\n";
    std::cout << TestFx("test") << "\n";

    return 0;
}

Works without issues in regular Visual Studio when compiling to an EXE:
1
5.5
test


Am I missing some compiler or linker flags here in order to enable templates to be compiled to a DLL using cl.exe?
Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) T __stdcall TestFx(T arg) {return arg;}  You can't export a template. You can instantiate the template and export that.

@drescherjm thanks for your comment; do you mean I would need to create explicit versions of my template for each datatype I plan to use, and manually export each one?

It's basically the "Alternative Solution" to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/495056/487892

You seemed to ignore the first error and post the second one. If you started fixing your code from the first error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition, you would find out that templates may not be declared with extern "C". This is compiled well
template <typename T>
__declspec(dllexport) T __stdcall TestFx(T arg) {
  return arg;
}

BTW I don't see any advantages of using __declspec(dllexport) and __stdcall with a template that is implemented in a header file.

I have not ignored any errors, I just uploaded an image of what my command prompt showed me when I attempted to compile the code. Also, when I try to compile the code you showed, I now get the error LNK1561: entry point must be defined. I'm also not doing this in a header file, it's a cpp file called test.cpp.

My code is only fixing the error. You must add main() like in your second code.

Alright so I messed around with the code a bit more, and made some discoveries. Alongside what you mentioned, another main issue was the fact that I was missing the /LD, /EHsc and /link flags in my cl.exe compile command, meaning it was trying to compile the code to an EXE rather than a DLL as I wanted, hence why I was getting the LNK1561 error as it couldn't find main(). Doing cl.exe /LD /EHsc /std:c++20 test.cpp /link /out:test.dll, and alongside the change you mentioned of removing the extern keyword, it now exports the DLL. However...

However, the exported test.dll doesn't appear to contain the function TestFx. Doing dumpbin /exports test.dll doesn't show the TestFx function as it should. Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

TestFx is a template, templates are not exported. They either should be instantiated for specific types in your DLL or the template must be in a header file.

ahh okay, so in other words, templates in this case will only generate versions of the function for datatype I explictly use it with, not for every possible datatype it can find. That makes sense, thank you. If you change your post reply to include that, I'll accept it as an answer.

Otherwise just leave the template in the header without the __declspec(dllexport) and __stdcall and use it the same way you would use it with no dll.
